# Apache: Common SetEnvIF Deny rules for Server-wide / apply on all the Domains?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, .htaccess

In my Apache, I have a long list of IPs to be blocked (for some reasons). And then I'm currently putting those rules inside the `.htaccess` files of the each and every single docroot (domains) I have.

The rules look like this:

```
SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "1.2.3.*" DenyIP
SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "100.200.*.*" DenyIP
..
..
..
..
..
..
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from env=DenyIP
```

These same `.htaccess` files are now located like:

```
/var/www/html/www.site-a.com/.htaccess
/var/www/html/www.site-b.com/.htaccess
/var/www/html/www.site-c.com/.htaccess
/var/www/html/www.site-d.com/.htaccess
/var/www/html/www.site-e.com/.htaccess
/var/www/html/www.site-f.com/.htaccess
/var/www/html/www.site-g.com/.htaccess
..
```

It works that way. But then whenever I have to update the IPs, I have to edit in all of these files.

### Question:

How do I apply these common rules **Server-wide** (Apache-wide), so that they are applied on every single websites docroots (domains) I have in my Apache?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **Apache 2.2** [Configuration Sections](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/sections.html) and [Access Control](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html).

- Directives [`Allow`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#allow) and [`Deny`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#deny) belongs to context: `Directory` and `.htaccess`.
- The `.htaccess` is a in-place equivalent for `<Directory>`, but with limitations, e.g.

  - You can't use `Include` inside `.htaccess`.
  - [`AllowOverride`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) controls what you can change with your `.htaccess` configuration.
- Configuration sections have merging order, shortened:

  > 1. `<Directory>` (except regular expressions) and `.htaccess` done simultaneously (with `.htaccess`, if allowed, overriding `<Directory>`)
  > 2. `<DirectoryMatch>` (and `<Directory ~>`)
  > 3. `<Files>` and `<FilesMatch>` done simultaneously
  > 4. `<Location>` and `<LocationMatch>` done simultaneously
- You can have global `<Directory>` sections outside `<VirtualHost>` sections:

  > Sections inside `<VirtualHost>` sections are applied after the corresponding sections outside the virtual host definition. This allows virtual hosts to override the main server configuration.

In short, inside your main `httpd.conf`, have this and don't override it in `<VirtualHost>`:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "1.2.3.*" DenyIP
    SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "100.200.*.*" DenyIP
    ..
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from env=DenyIP
</Directory>
```

If you don't want to have the long `SetEnvIF` list in `httpd.conf`, use [`Include][6]`:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Include /path/to/SetEnvIF-list.conf
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from env=DenyIP
</Directory>
```

---

Notice what all the documentation linked here mentions:

> This document refers to the 2.2 version of Apache httpd, which is no
>   longer maintained. The active release is documented [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current). If you have
>   not already upgraded, please follow [this link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/upgrading.html) for more information.

[Access Control in **Apache 2.4**](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html) is a bit different, but you'll be able to use environment variables with its mod_authz_core [`Require`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require)`env`. As you set the variable for *deny* instead of *allow*, you'd need to use `not` before the `env` entity-name.

```
SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "1.2.3.*" DenyIP
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Require not env DenyIP
</Directory>
```